# loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys and multiple values loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avfoundation

I would like to asynchronously load the duration, time (timestamp the video was created) and locale of an Asset.

All of the sample code shown by Apple for the usage of `'loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys'` is always shows with only one key. ie:

```
NSURL *url = aUrl; 
AVAsset asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"duration"];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() {

NSError *error = nil;
AVKeyValueStatus durationStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"duration" error:&error];

switch (durationSatus) {
    case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
            // Read duration from asset
            CMTime assetDurationInCMTime = [asset duration];            
        break;

        case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
            // Report error
        break; 

        case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
        // Do whatever is appropriate for cancelation   
    }
}];
```

Can I assume that if one item's status is 'AVKeyValueStatusLoaded', the other values can be read at the same time in the completion block? ie:

```
[asset tracks]
[asset commonMetadata];
[asset duration]
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't assume that. One of my methods looks at two keys, playable and duration, and I have found that playable is often available while duration isn't yet. I therefor have moved the loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys: code into a separate method shouldSave:. The shouldSave: method I call from a timer in a method called saveWithDuration:. Once saveWithDuration: receives a non-zero duration, it goes ahead and saves stuff. To avoid waiting too long, I use an attempt counter for now -- in the future, I'll refine this (you'll notice that the error instance isn't really used at the moment)

```
- (void)shouldSave:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
NSString * const TBDuration = @"duration";
NSString * const TBPlayable = @"playable";

__block float theDuration = TBZeroDuration;
__block NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *assetKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:TBDuration, TBPlayable, nil];

[_audioAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:assetKeys completionHandler:^() {

    AVKeyValueStatus playableStatus = [_audioAsset statusOfValueForKey:TBPlayable error:&error];
    switch (playableStatus) {
        case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
            //go on
            break;
        default:
            return; 
    }

    AVKeyValueStatus durationStatus = [_audioAsset statusOfValueForKey:TBDuration error:&error];
    switch (durationStatus) {
        case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
            theDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(_audioAsset.duration);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}];

NSUInteger attempt = [[[theTimer userInfo] objectForKey:TBAttemptKey] integerValue];
attempt++;
[self saveWithDuration:theDuration attempt:attempt error:&error];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can't. The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler: says that

> The completion states of the keys you
>   specify in keys are not necessarily
>   the same—some may be loaded, and
>   others may have failed. You must check
>   the status of each key individually.

In practice, I think this is often a safe assumption -- as you've noted, Apple's StitchedStreamPlayer sample project just looks at the status of the first key.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot assume so. I usually rely on `@"duration"` key to create an `AVPlayerItem` and start playback since loading of `@"playable"` generally doesn't guarantee that the asset is ready yet. Then I spawn a timer to check periodically whether others keys such as `@"tracks"` are loaded or not similar to what Elise van Looij has mentioned above.

Also, side note - do remember that the `completionHandler` in `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys` is called on an arbitrary background thread. You will have to dispatch it to main thread if you are dealing with UI or AVPlayerLayer.